# How can i pass model to view in asp.net core 5.0 mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, n-tier-architecture

Im trying to pass that data to my view. I allready look around what can i do or which way i can use or something but im still getting null exception error when i call that `ViewBag.passData`.

Here its my `BaseController` :

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public BaseViewModel baseViewModel;

        public readonly IUnitOfWork<SiteSetting> _unitOfWorkSiteSetting;
        public readonly IUnitOfWork<Category> _unitOfWorkCat;

        public BaseController(
            IUnitOfWork<SiteSetting> unitOfWorkSiteSetting,
            IUnitOfWork<Category> unitOfWorkCat)
        {
            _unitOfWorkSiteSetting = unitOfWorkSiteSetting;
            _unitOfWorkCat = unitOfWorkCat;

           baseViewModel = new BaseViewModel
            {
                SiteSettings = _unitOfWorkSiteSetting.RepositorySiteSettings.GetSiteSettingsByID(2),//1-Admin,2-Shopping,3-WebFair
                IsFeaturedCategories = _unitOfWorkCat.RepositoryCategory.IsFeaturedCategoriesAsNoTracing(10)
            };
            ViewBag.passData = baseViewModel;
        }
    }
```

as u can see im filling up my `BaseViewModel` in that `BaseController`.
im trying to do that because im calling those data in every page.
when i call that `ViewBag.passData`  in my view,im getting null exception error.

Here its my view :

```
@model IndexViewModel;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Anasayfa";
    Layout = null;
    BaseViewModel baseViewModel = new BaseViewModel();
    baseViewModel = ViewBag.passData; ***//The point where i am getting that error***
    var siteKey = Configuration.GetSection("GoogleRecaptcha").GetSection("RecaptchaV3SiteKey").Value ?? "";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <partial name="_HeadPartial" />
    <!-- RECAPTCHA JS-->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=@siteKey"></script>
    <!-- RECAPTCHA JS-->
</head>
It goes like that....
```

I allready check it out my `BaseController` and its working well.

**Thanks for any suggestion!**

Answer (score 0):

You can do return View(VieModel)

Then in your .cshtml view you can add @model of the type you passed into the view

Answer (score 0):

To return to a certain view with a certain model, do this:

return View("ViewName",viewModel);